# Al seleccionar una fecha en mi input date que automaticamente traiga el dia , año y mes en otro Input por separados hay alguna forma en php javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy tratando de encontrar una manera de poder que el valor de un input de tipo fecha se me separe en tres input tipo hidden de forma que eso datos se envíen de forma oculta ejemplo:

Selecciono: 11/12/2023

Y que en un input coloque: 11 en otro coloque: 2023 Y que adicionalmente en otro input coloque solo el nombre del mes ejemplo: NOVIEMBRE

Asi tengo el codigo del Input Type Date:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <label  class="ms-2">Fecha</label>
 <input class="form-control" type="date" name="Fecha" id="Fecha" required>
 </div>
```

Se puede hacer con Javascript y PHP?

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Realiza el recorrido para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour 3. Lecturas recomendadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 4. Para que tengas mayor chance de conseguir respuesta, edita la pregunta e incluye lo que has intentado, lo que has investigado, de ese modo también evitas votos negativos. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un input del tipo `date` te retorna la fecha (objeto del tipo `Date`) con la propiedad `valueAsDate`, además usas el evento `oninput` para detectar cuando cambia esta fecha

A partir de un objeto `Date`, puedes obtener:

- El día con `getUTCDate()`
- El mes con `getUTCMonth()`  (un número del 0 al 11, 0 es febrero)
- El año con `getUTCFullYear()`

Ojo hay otras 3 funciones similares (sin UTC) `getDate`, `getMonth` y `getFullYear`, estas te retornan los valores en hora local, pero el `input[type=date]` retorna en UTC-0, por eso hay que usar las que yo señalo.

Ahora para obtener el mes en texto, puedes crear un array con los meses

Aquí un ejemplo

```js
const MESES_LIST=["ENERO","FEBRERO","MARZO","ABRIL","MAYO","JUNIO","JULIO","AGOSTO","SEPTIEMBRE","OCTUBRE","NOVIEMBRE","DICIEMBRE"];


function setHidden(){
  const f = event.target.valueAsDate;
  if(!f) return;
  
  dia.value = f.getUTCDate();
  mes.value = MESES_LIST[f.getUTCMonth()];
  ano.value = f.getUTCFullYear();
}
```

```html
<input id="Fecha" type="date" oninput="setHidden()">
<input id="dia" > <!-- <input id="dia" type="hidden"> -->
<input id="mes" > <!-- <input id="mes" type="hidden"> -->
<input id="ano" > <!-- <input id="ano" type="hidden"> -->
```

Comment: Bro, entiendo tus ganas de ayudar y todo lo que hay detrás y me parece excelente; solo un detalle, sigue atendiendo a preguntas que al menos tengan algo de código de algún intento, aunque sea algo mínimo, se recompensa el esfuerzo, ¿verdad?.

Comment: Gracias me ha servido perfecto, lamento no haber colocado el código completo con el JS.